# Unrecognized devices keep appearing in bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

My question is rather simple, and image will be attached for a visual indicator of what I referring to.
For months now, on Ubuntu 20 all the way to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS,when I got to my Bluetooth in settings. This recurring "ALAM(XX:XX:XX)"  x's appear to be hexadecimal values. I cannot tell if it is picking up different devices or if a device continuously cycles one of its own identifiers and are appearing separately. Is this normal behaviour?

[This is what the device list shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tTwT.png)

Is there anyone that knows what this might be, as I am aware of all my Bluetooth devices and this represents none of them.Will clarify if needed.

Comment: My Sony bluetooth headphones cycle through two identifiers occasionally when they're not paired to anything, so maybe this is similar although 5 separate identifiers sounds like a lot. Do you have any neighbours close by, such as in an apartment next door? Your computer might be picking up their devices.

Comment: @ccbirb That is what I was thinking. My neighbors are awfully far for bluetooth to be picked up although I can't say for sure if far enough to be voiding all signals. Thank you for your response.

Comment: "ALAM Bluetooth" google search suggests nothing useful to identify the device but, at first glance this seems a too common typo in many stores, meaning "alarm". Do you have some sort of alarm device with Buetooth?